# Php default image when image not exist

Tags: php, image, if-statement, get, default

i have a little script for my cms. I'm trying to create a default image (default.png) when image linked not exist. I have all images in another website and i created this code:

```
<?php 
$immagine_e = $_GET('http://www.website.com/images/'.$provincia'.png');
?>
<?php if ($immagine_e ==''){ ?> 
<img src="images/default.png" class="margin-top-negative-70" alt="">
<?php } else { ?> 
<img src="$immagine_e" class="margin-top-negative-70" alt="">
<?php } ?>
```

$provincia = name of city. For example *milano* and if http://www.website.com/images/milano.png not exist i need default images. If exist i need this image.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API: https://placehold.it/

**Example:**

```
<?php 
$immagine_e = $_GET('http://www.website.com/images/'.$provincia'.png');
?>
<?php if ($immagine_e ==''){ ?> 
<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="margin-top-negative-70" alt="">
<?php } else { ?> 
<img src="$immagine_e" class="margin-top-negative-70" alt="">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that you can consider.

```
$immagine_e = "http://www.website.com/images/$provincia.png";
$size = getimagesize($immagine_e);
 if(isset($size[0]))
 {
 ?>
   <img src="$immagine_e" class="margin-top-negative-70" alt="">
  <?
 }else
 {
 ?>
   <img src="images/default.png" class="margin-top-negative-70" alt="">
 <?
 }
```

Comment: i can consider... but i need also a dinamyc link with $provincia

Comment: @Weadom - There you go, neatly hand crafted for ya.